# Find point spectrum and spectrum of integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, integral-operators

Let $A:L^2(0,\pi) \to L^2(0,\pi)$ be defined by $(Af)(x)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^\pi \sin(x-y)f(y)dy$. Find the point spectrum and spectrum of $A$.

I am not sure how to go about this. I thought to start with, I should find the point spectrum (i.e. the set of eigenvalues). So not knowing any techniques for integral operators, I would just set $\displaystyle\int_{0}^\pi \sin(x-y)f(y)dy=\lambda f(x)$ and try to solve for $f$. Unfortunately I have no idea how to, or even if it is possible, to solve for $f$ here. I am wondering if there is a trick specific to this integrand or a more general technique regarding integral operators that I should know about. I have a result that tells me $A$ is compact but it's not clear how this  could be used. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $Af(x) = (\sin\star f)(x)$, where $\star$ denotes convolution.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117098/spectrum-of-convolution-integral-operator

Comment: We have never actually seen or used Fourier transforms so far, so it is strange that we would be set such an exercise. I suppose there is no more elementary way of finding the spectrum, or by using the spectral theory for compact operators?

Comment: $A$ is a compact operator, so it is not invertible. Hence $0$ is in the spectrum. For a compact operator non-zero points in the spectrum are all eigen values. Hence it is enough to find eigen values which has been done by Jacky Chong.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $A$ is a compact operator because it is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator?

Comment: @Math1000 If you expand $\sin (x-y)$ as $\sin\,x \cos ,y-\cos\, x \sin\, y$ you will see that the range of $A$ is contained in the span of sin and cos. Any finite rank operator is compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
Tf(x)=\int^\pi_0 \sin(x-y) f(y)\ dy = \left(\int^\pi_0 \cos(y)f(y)\ dy\right) \sin(x)-\left(\int^\pi_0 \sin(y)f(y)\ dy\right)\cos(x)
\end{align}
which means $\mathcal{R}(T) = \operatorname{span}\{\cos(x), \sin(x)\}$ and $\dim\mathcal{R}(T)=2$. Next, consider $f(x) = A\cos(x)+ B\sin(x)$, then we see that
\begin{align}
Tf(x) = \frac{\pi A}{2}\sin(x)-\frac{\pi B}{2}\cos(x) = \lambda (A\cos(x)+ B\sin(x))
\end{align}
iff $\lambda A = -\frac{\pi B}{2}$ and $\lambda B= \frac{\pi A}{2}$. Solving for $A$ and $B$ yields
\begin{align}
\lambda^2  +\frac{\pi^2}{4} =0 \ \ \implies \ \ \lambda = \pm \frac{\pi}{2}i
\end{align}
which means $f_1(x) = \cos(x)-i\sin(x)$ and $f_2(x) = \cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ are both eigenfunctions of $T$.

**Remark:** Note that if $L^2(0, \pi)$ is viewed as a real vector space, then $T$ has no real eigenvalue other than $0$.

Comment: Great answer, might be worth mentioning that the first equality is due to $\sin(x-y)=\sin(x)\cos(y) - \sin(y)\cos(x)$ though. At first I thought you invoked integration by parts which was confusing.

Comment: Somehow I forgot that I could expand the sine. Very nice solution for the point spectrum. However I don't see how to get the full spectrum from here. The operator isn't self-adjoint so I can't use that the spectrum is the closure of the point spectrum.

Comment: @AlephNull Note the operator is compact.

Comment: Yeah I did some googling and found results such as '$0$ is in the spectrum of a compact operator on an infinite-dimensional space' and 'for compact operators, every nonzero element of the spectrum is an eigenvalue'. Strangely I have not come across such results before. Not even sure why this type of operator is compact. But I suppose I should look into these things separately.

Comment: @JackyChong How would one show that $0$ is an eigenvalue?

Comment: @DLB Hint: You are mapping from an infinite-dimensional space to a 2-dimensional space.

Comment: @JackyChong I pondered on this and being infinite dimensional means we can find an infinite sequence of linearly independent functions. But I was struggling to use this and construct an orthogonal function to sine and cosine in L2

Comment: @Hint: Try $\sin(nx)$ from some $n$ (not every $n$ will work).