# Find the spectrum of $(Ff)(x)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (1 + \cos(x-y))f(y)dy$

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

As the title suggests we have a function $T: L^2 [-\pi,\pi] \to L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ that sends $f \to \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (1 + \cos(x-y))f(y)dy$.

I have read a couple of related posts, but unfortunately I am not sure how to proceed. Most of what I read either worked with Fourier transforms (I see that if $K(x)=1+cos(x)$, then the expression we have is $K$ convoluted with $f$) or directly by finding point spectrum and invoking some property where doing this sufficed to compute the total spectrum.

I did not succed with the first one, and after that went to try to compute the point spectrum. What I get is that $\pi$ and $2\pi$ are the (point) spectrum, and any function of the form $ b_1 \cos(t) +  b_2 \sin(t)$ and $b_0$ (constant one) are their corresponding eigenfunctions, respectively. To do this I just worked out the expression, using the fact that we can rewrite $\cos(x-y)$ as $\cos(x)\cos(y)+\sin(x)\sin(y)$. From here I got that the image of our map can be written as $a_1 + a_2\cos(t) +  a_3 \sin(t)$, from where I deduced that these are the unique eigenvalues after some computations.

What approach do you guys suggest? Does my function have any special properties (like compactness or self adjointess) to conlude this is it? Is the Fourier transformation easier here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just found another eigenvalue now, sorry for the edit.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117098/spectrum-of-convolution-integral-operator

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But here the answer would be the range of $\hat{K}$ right? If yes what are the concrete numbers? I tried this but it got messy. @cmk

Comment: So you suggest it is just $[0,2]$? @cmk Could you please make a more explicit argument? Thanks.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank for your comment. Some questions: How do you find the Kernel of the operator and why is it important? Being a HS operator in a separable Hilbert space implies it is compact, according to wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator. Two more questions: Where does your equality implying self adjointness comes from? Could you send some references? And lastly, this would all imply that the spectrum is the closure of the point spectrum, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@cmk is right. Look at that post. But if you want a more specific answer for your specific convolution kernel, here goes. (But please then look at the link that [cmk](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/671645/cmk) suggested afterwards.)

Take $\psi_k(x) = e^{i k x}$. Then $F \psi_k = \lambda_k \psi_k$ where $\lambda_0=2\pi$, $\lambda_1=\lambda_{-1}=\pi$ and $\lambda_k=0$ for $k \not\in \{-1,0,1\}$. That is a complete orthonormal basis. So the spectrum is pure-point. It is a rank-3 self-adjoint operator. Just integrate to get these results: multiplying by $(2\pi)^{-1}$ you get
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(1+\frac{1}{2} e^{i x} e^{-iy} + \frac{1}{2} e^{-ix} e^{iy}\right) e^{i k y}\, dy\, ,
$$
which is equal to the expression utilizing $L^2$-inner products
$$
\langle \psi_0\, ,\ \psi_k\rangle\, \psi_0(x) 
+ \frac{1}{2} \langle \psi_1\, ,\ \psi_k\rangle\, \psi_1(x)
+ \frac{1}{2} \langle \psi_{-1}\, ,\ \psi_k\rangle\, \psi_{-1}(x)\, ,
$$
using the mathematicians' convention for sesquilinearity.

Comment: Thank you. But what is an eigenfunction corresponding to the eigenvalue of 0?

Comment: Or you mean that only $\pi$ and $ 2 \pi$ are the eigenvalues?

Comment: For example, for $\psi_2(x) = e^{4 \pi i x}$, you have $\mathcal{F} \psi_2 = 0$ even though $\psi_2$ is not a zero-function. So it is an eigenfunction with corresponding eigenvalue $0$. Are you asking about the definition, or are you asking what are they? All $\psi_k$'s for $k \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{-1,0,1\}$ are eigenfunctons corresponding to eigenvalue $0$. They are all in the kernel of $\mathcal{F}$ and the closure of their span is the kernel of $\mathcal{F}$.