# Fourier transform of time series by diagonalising matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, time-series

Does there exist a case where the Fourier transform of a time series is found via diagonalising a matrix? Ideally, I am looking for cases where the eigenvalues correspond to frequencies.

Any leads are helpful, thank you!

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that such a "case" exists? Any context you add to your question would be helpful here.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, if you consider a Hamiltonian describing a quantum harmonic oscillator, e.g. here https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node258.html the eigenvalues correspond to frequencies. That is just the most basic example, there are other systems where particles' energy levels correspond to eigenvalues/eigenfrequencies. Is that a peculiarity of quantum mechanics or do there exist other models/formalisms where that is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important context in which eigenvalues correspond to frequencies of a "Fourier transform" of sorts is the case of a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix)
$$
C = \begin{bmatrix}
c_0      & c_{n-1} & \cdots  & c_2     & c_1     \\
c_1      & c_0     & c_{n-1} &         & c_2     \\
\vdots   & c_1     & c_0     & \ddots  & \vdots  \\
c_{n-2}  &         & \ddots  & \ddots  & c_{n-1} \\
c_{n-1}  & c_{n-2} & \cdots  & c_1     & c_0     \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
In this case, the eigenvalues of $C$ are precisely the [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) of the vector $c = (c_0,c_1,\dots,c_{n-1})$. Notably, the operator associated with $C$ is the [discrete circular convolution operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution#Discrete_sequences) $x \mapsto c*_n x$.

If we want our "eigenvalues" to correspond to the full Fourier transform of a function, we need to move into the infinite dimensional setting. For a function $f$ for which $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|^2\,dx$ is finite, we can consider the convolution operator defined so that
$$
T_f(g)(t) = (f*g)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau) g(t-\tau) d\tau.
$$
The eigenvalues of this operator consist precisely of the range of the Fourier transform $\hat f$ of $f$. Similarly, if we consider the operator $T_f$ over the space of periodic functions on $[-\pi,\pi]$ given by
$$
T_f(g)(t) = (f\hat *g)(t) = \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(\tau) g(t-\tau) d\tau,
$$
Then the eigenvalues of $T_f$ consists precisely of [the values appearing in the Fourier series of $f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1117098/81360).