A doubt in the proof of the spectrum of convolution operator
The following is a link showing the spectrum of convolution operator $A f(x)= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} h(x-y) f(y) dy$ $L^2( {-\pi},{\pi})->L^2( {-\pi},{\pi})$ is range of $h$ where $h$ is continuous periodic on $[-\pi,\pi]$: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1117156/1067823.
The answer takes the Fourier transform and results in a multiplication operator $M_h: L^2[-\pi,\pi] \to L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ so that $M_h:= \hat{h}(x)f(x)$ and solve the original problem by looking at the spectrum of $M_h$.  $\hat{h}$ being the Fourier Transform of $h$ is continuous. $(M_h -\lambda I)f=(\hat{h}-\lambda)f$. Indeed, if $\lambda \notin range(\hat{h})$, $M_h-\lambda I$ is invertible and bounded.
However, I'm wondering if the converse also holds (the proof in the link says it't trivial and skipped that): If $M_h-\lambda I$ is invertible, then $\lambda \in range(\hat{h})$. Because any $L^2$ function can have essential singularity, then it's also possible that for $\lambda \in range(\hat{h})$ and $\frac{g(x)}{\hat{h}-\lambda}\in L^2$ with singularity. Is there anyway to construct a $g\in L^2$ such that the integral of the square of $\frac{g(x)}{\hat{h}-\lambda}$ blows up?

The spectrum of the multiplication operator is the essential range of $\hat h$

@EvangelopoulosFoivos Yes, but I'm doubting the proof of this fact in the link. Is it just a matter of dividing a non-zero number?

You want to show that if $\lambda\in\operatorname{range}\hat h$ (meaning the essential range) then $M_h-\lambda I$ is not invertible. Note that $M_h-\lambda I=M_{\hat h-\lambda}$, so we may assume without loss of generality that $\lambda=0$.
From the definition of the essential range, having $0$ in the essential range of $h$ means that for each $n\in\mathbb N$ you have $m(h^{-1}(B_{1/n}(0)))>0$, where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure (the argument works for any finite measure). Let
$$
F_n=h^{-1}(B_{1/n}(0)),\qquad g_n=\frac1{m(F_n)^{1/2}}\,1_{F_n}. 
$$
We have $\|g_n\|_2=1$ and, since $|h|<\frac1n$ on $F_n$,
$$
\|M_hg_n\|_2^2=\frac1{m(f_n)^{1/2}}\int_{F_n} |h|^2\leq\frac{m(F_n)^{1/2}}{n^2}\leq\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{n^2}. 
$$
So $M_hg_n\to0$ while $\|g_n\|_2=1$, and then $M_h$ is not bounded below, which prevents it from being invertible.
